# Why is my fetch request being called twice?

Tags: javascript

```
API = {
    get_processed_autodesk_results : function(){
            fetch('/api/results', {
                method: 'get',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(res=>res.json())
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log(res);   

            });
    }
} 

setInterval(API.get_processed_autodesk_results,5000);
```

That is my code. I check the console and see that the fetch request is being executed twice every 5 seconds. I can't figure out why this is happening. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Only runs once every five seconds if I try it. Almost definitely the problem is in something you're not showing us. Maybe the `setInterval` line is being called twice?

Comment: Is that `setInterval()` call in some function that might get called more than once?

Comment: Maybe it's better if you use a debugger

Comment: setInterval is inside a function called `Template.render()` that gets called once when the page loads.

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr And what calls `Template.render()`? Have you verified that it is only called once?

Comment: `Template.render()` is inside a `document.onreadystatechange = () => {}` . I put a `console.log('page loaded')` to confirm it is only called once. This is indeed the case.

Comment: It might be an `OPTIONS` request (a pre-flight request) that you see. Check what the `Request Method` for both requests are using devtools -> Network. This is just an idea, but I guess this isn't the case given that it's a GET request to your own server, on the same domain.

Comment: I think you're right @MathiasW, about it being an OPTIONS request.

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr Are you saying that the `console.log(res)` is logging twice every five seconds, or that the browser tools' Network tab is showing two requests every five seconds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The additional fetch request you are seeing is an `OPTIONS` request (pre-flight request) which is occurs when headers are passed in the request.

[Excerpt from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests):

> Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), "preflighted" requests
>   first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on
>   the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is
>   safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they
>   may have implications to user data.

You can test requesting with and without headers and see what happens by checking developer tools here:

https://jsfiddle.net/219n4a0b/

Comment: It sounds like OP is saying that the console is logging twice every five seconds. An OPTIONS request wouldn't cause that.

Comment: It would, try my fiddle and you'll see that exact behavior @JLRishe

Comment: I did try your fiddle, and it only logged once to the console per button click. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are testing with Chrome, don't filter on XHR.

Comment: Are you talking about the Network tab, or the console? I'm talking about the consolle, which I presume OP is talking about, though it's not entirely clear. Yes, the Network tab shows two requests. The console only shows one line per `fetch`.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the Networks tab. One log per request is expected regardless of options or not. If OP is seeing 2 logs per request then I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem but it turns out it was because my routes were going through the service worker which again requested and returned the request so the server got 2 requests 1 from the main fetch an another from the service workers fetch.

EDIT
**facepalm**
yea I am new to pwas and all so was using return instead of respondWith()